# how to install gdal_proximity

Tags: installation, gdal

I installed gdal with the `apt-get install gdal-bin` command.
Then this is what I get :

```
# ls /usr/bin | grep gdal   
gdal-config
gdal_contour
gdal_grid
gdal_rasterize
gdal_translate
gdaladdo
gdalbuildvrt
gdaldem
gdalenhance
gdalinfo
gdallocationinfo
gdalmanage
gdalserver
gdalsrsinfo
gdaltindex
gdaltransform
gdalwarp
```

There is no gdal_proximity but it is stated in the doc that it will be installed with gdal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install `python-gdal`, it works now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gdal_proximity.py is not included in the Ubuntu `gdal-bin` repository. [gdal-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/gdal-bin)

You should be able to directly copy/download the source file and use it, since it is just a python script. [gdal_proximity.py](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_proximity.py)

Copy the file into your `bin` or `/usr/bin` or somewhere in your `PATH`. Give it execution permission `chmod +x gdal_proximity.py` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I found the package witch contains it, python-gdal